# What type of line breaks does a Python script normally have?

Tags: python, python-2.x, line-breaks

My boss keeps getting annoyed at me for having Windows line breaks in my Python scripts, but I can't for the life of me work out how they are causing him a problem.

Is '\r\n' the normal line-break for a Python script? Or does that only happen on [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29) for PC?

PS: OK, it seems when I write the script on a Mac that it has '\n's, but is there any way that '\r\n' will cause a problem?

Edit:
OK... now I'm totally confused. When I interpret files written in Windows in Python they all spit out when I print lines to the screen as '\n'. Does the Python interpreter for Windows translate line-breaks?

Comment: Are you using source control???

Comment: why shouldn't i be using IDLE if i have a boss? the comment makes no sense?

Comment: Yes it does. If you work in an environment where people share code, and if they work on different platforms, you need editors that don't break other people's work because of OS differences.

Comment: and no, not using any formal source control, but i'm the only one working on the script.

Comment: i can't work out where it's breaking for him though, i can't find anything that won't run or display it with the windows line breaks.

Comment: Can you ask your boss? We doctors have a saying "If all else fails, go back and ask the patient."

Comment: hahaha sorry, every time I read an Ignacio Vazquez comment is a rager comment XD

Comment: i still don't get what he means? technically he's an adviser/supervisor, "boss" was just a shorter word.

Comment: @Bec - ignore it.  It was a silly and mean-spirited jab at you, and nothing you deserved.

Comment: @Kirt, you are "the only one working on your code" but "it's breaking" for your "boss". Clearly you're *not* the only one working on your code. (Unix) newlines are the standard line-ending and there's some options in `git` to handle checking out and back in so that Windows users don't break everything. I'm sure if you start using `git` you'll never look back. It's very useful: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings . I can't see any offensive comments here (maybe deleted) but the comment from Tim Pietzcker is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Python but with the underlying OS. If you save a text file on Windows, you get CRLF linebreaks, if you save it on Mac/Unix systems, you get LF linebreaks (and on stone-age Macs, CR linebreaks).

Use an editor that allows you to preserve the line break format of your files. No, Notepad doesn't, but most editors I've seen do. UltraEdit and EditPadPro are the ones I know, and I can recommend both. I'm pretty sure that IDEs like PyDev/Eclipse will handle that too, but I haven't tried.

Comment: it seems IDLE for PC uses '\r\n' but it's possible i opened the file in wordpad or similar at some point. I'll have to do a bit of experimenting when i get home.

Comment: Of course IDLE uses `\r\n` *if you run it on Windows*. That's the whole point of my answer. You need to use an editor that consciously ignores the platform it's running on when saving a text file.

Comment: @Bec: Can't reproduce this here. Looking at a Python file (that I just created in IDLE) in a hex editor, I see `0D0A` line endings. Anything else wouldn't make any sense. If you load a text file using `open(filename, "r")` in Python, all `\r\n` are interpreted as `\n` *by the Python interpreter*, but on disk they still have `\r\n` line endings. That's why there are "open as binary" options - `open(filename, "rb")` etc. - where line endings are left alone. But again, this is nothing Python-specific.

Comment: The "underlying OS" generally doesn't care, it's all about editors and conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Make a Python script which replaces '\r\n' with '\n'

An run it every time you give the code to your boss.

:)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. Yes, doing a simple find-and-replace should fix this problem. However you'll have to do it every time you share code; you might want to think about automating it somehow. I never did do that myself.

Answer (score 0):

This [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) one-liner will convert the Python script to have the desired line endings:

```
sed 's/\r\n/\n/g' <windows_script >unix_script
```

Answer (score 0):

**newlines** (`\n`), as opposed to carriage-return/linefeeds (`\n\r`), are pretty much the canonical line ending everywhere, except for dedicated Windows-only enclaves.

You shouldn't really be repeatedly manually converting line endings. That's not really a "Good Thing" Ⓡ.

To support this, `git` has the `core.autocrlf` option. When enabled on Windows systems, files with standard newline endings will be converted to CRLF when checked out, and converted back on the way back in.

This seems to be a seamless way to cope with the problem of Windows line-endings when running GUI editors and IDEs on Windows. Your editor is probably expecting CRLF line endings on Windows and will get them when using `git` with this option, which I believe is set to `true` by default on Windows installs.

If you're not using Git, maybe it's time you did? Even when working alone it has lots of value. You can version your own code for backing up and providing alternates.

Some users will be using GitBash / Cygwin / Ming tools on Windows, possibly with GitBash supplied `vim`, and will not appreciate CRLF line-endings. Those users can turn the Git `core.autocrlf` setting off (`false`) *before* cloning a repo to avoid inappropriate "corrections", and thereby see proper newline-only line endings when editing files, even on Windows. This may also help when using other Linux tools when running on Windows that also expect newline line endings.

Git has three levels of settings: "system" (probably set in `C:\Program Files\...`), "global" (set in your home directory Git config file and affecting all your repos) and "local" set in each repo's `.git/config` file. Latter levels override the former levels, which can be helpful if your organisation has locked down your C drive.

Here are some of the Git commands to query and update your settings (and you can just edit the configuration files themselves as well):

- `git config --list --show-origin`: Lists all your settings and the file locations where they are set. A setting may be repeated so the lower level will override the higher.
- `git config --get core.autocrlf`: Get the effective setting from the combination of settings you currently have in place.
- `git config --system core.autocrlf false`: Switch off automatic conversion at the system level, for all repos.
- `git config --global core.autocrlf false`: Switch off automatic conversion in all repos from your home directory config file.

Remember, set `core.autocrlf` to what you need *before* you clone. Reference here: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings